# Azure Graph API update for admins

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

By default Azure graph protocol does not allow updating admins using API, and that is why the sync between 3rd party and Azure does not work when provisioning is setup.

What needs to be done in this case for the azure admins? How will the data be update for those users?

Comment: Are you trying to update the user info using that API?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to update the user info in Azure using API

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are updating an users that has global adminsitator role.

Make Sure to update those users you need also global admins role.Not all properties can be updated by Member or Guest users with their default permissions without Administrator roles.

following permissions is required to call this API.

[image]

[image]

I am trying to update the bussiness phone number and office location using patch operation by passing the json value in request body.

**Graph API** : `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}`

[image]

[image]

You can refer this [***MS Document***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for more information.

Comment: I have given Directory and User Read Write all permission to the user who is trying to update the global admin info via API and still can't do it.

Error: Authentication_RequestDenied - Insufficient Privilages

Comment: the user should also have global admin privileges from which account you are trying to update admin details.